# How to align two image in a tag next to each other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am used two images button and place them in a `a` tag in the same bootstrap column. However this is how they look like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<body>

    <div class="backgroundImage">
        <div class="text-right p-3">
            <a href="/register-dealer " class="btn p-2"><b>{{ __('Be A Dealer') }}</b></a>
        </div>


        <div class="container mt-4 mb-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-md-4 mx-auto my-auto">
                    <img class="mw-100" src="{{ asset('storage/logo/Bujishu_logo.png') }}" alt="Bujishu">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
                    <h2 class="bujishu-motto">
                        A home is made of
                        <i>
                            <p class="bujishu-recursive">hopes</p>
                        </i>
                        and
                        <i>
                            <p class="bujishu-recursive">dreams</p>
                        </i>
                    </h2>
                    <h2 class="bujishu-motto">
                        Let us
                        <i>
                            <p class="bujishu-recursive">inspire</p>
                        </i>
                        you to build the perfect home!
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4 offset-md-3 ">
                    <a href="/login " class="grad2"><img class="landing_button" src="{{ asset('storage/buttons/Login-Icon.png') }}" alt="Login"></a>
                  
                {{-- </div>

                <div class="col-6 col-md-4  "> --}}
                   
                    <a href="/register" class="grad2"><img class="landing_button"  src="{{ asset('storage/buttons/Sign-Up.png') }}" alt="Sign Up"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

How do I align so the next two buttons are next to each other with some spacing between them as well?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<h2>` and a `<i>` may not contain a `<p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `d-flex` and class in your `col`.

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 offset-md-3 d-flex">
```

You can also add `pl-3` class to `SIGN UP` button for the space between the buttons.

Comment: and i put them in two seperate columns?

Comment: No, in the same column

Comment: is there any diff separating into two columns?

Comment: Actually there is not much difference for using multiple columns or the same column. But, it is better to use multiple columns instead of using d-flex class because by using d-flex you are making your column similar to row. Using row and col in appropriate places is always better. For your case, you can use col-auto for each button column

Comment: But the spacing looks fine on my chrome dev tools on iphone but when I deployed on server and test on actual mobile device, the two buttons overlap. may i know why? It works fine on android but on iphone it doesn't

Comment: Your CSS file may be cached in your iphone. If not, it is about Safari. You can try editing css on Safari developer console of a MacBook.

Comment: So it's not a code problem? I spent hours trying to figure out why it works on my chrome dev and other phones but not on iphone models.

Comment: Also, do you mind giving me an upvote on my quest. would appreciate it

Comment: I gave. Actually, I did not understand why people downvote your question.

Comment: I tried to use offset when on mobile layout, I use offset-xs-3 and tried offset-sm-3 but both doesn't reflect any changes. why?

Comment: Instead of offset you can add an empty div with col-3

Comment: It's not a good practice to use empty div, it's better to use offset. I change offset for md and it works for desktop layout but adding offset sm does not reflect changes to mobile layout via chrome tools, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 it will work if you use two columns, each of size 6 or you can change the size of columns accordingly.

```
<body>
<div class="backgroundImage">

            <div class="text-right p-3">
                <a href="/register-dealer " class="btn p-2"><b>{{ __('Be A Dealer') }}</b></a>
            </div>


            <div class="container mt-4 mb-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4 col-md-4 mx-auto my-auto">
                        <img class="mw-100" src="{{ asset('storage/logo/Bujishu_logo.png') }}" alt="Bujishu">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
                        <h2 class="bujishu-motto">
                            A home is made of
                            <i>
                                <p class="bujishu-recursive">hopes</p>
                            </i>
                            and
                            <i>
                                <p class="bujishu-recursive">dreams</p>
                            </i>
                        </h2>
                        <h2 class="bujishu-motto">
                            Let us
                            <i>
                                <p class="bujishu-recursive">inspire</p>
                            </i>
                            you to build the perfect home!
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row mt-4">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
                        <a href="/login " class="grad2"><img class="landing_button" src="{{ asset('storage/buttons/Login-Icon.png') }}" alt="Login"></a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6">

                        <a href="/register" class="grad2"><img class="landing_button"  src="{{ asset('storage/buttons/Login-Icon.png') }}" alt="Sign Up"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: how come I tried adding offset-sm or xs for mobile layout on chrome dev tools, it does not reflect changes for mobile?

Comment: try using col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 for the column, its working for me

Comment: you can change the column size as per your requirement

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hamadjaved/v2epyx9m/
check out this, you may be facing issue because of the image size adding the `width: 100%` will solve the issue. Kindly check the fiddle you'll get my point

Comment: have you checked the demo?

Comment: Yes, I am confused, which issue are you trying to solve? The button not align issue or the mobile issue?

Comment: The mobile issue, i have tried to explain that how col-sm and offset is working in that example.

Comment: I told you I use your col-sm is not working for me. I tried col-xs as well. So what gives?

Comment: instead of col-xs just use col-* because col-xs is not supported in Bootstrap 4.3. I have made the demo for this purpose so that you can check how it is working. Kindly check the demo here. https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-browser-l87qi

Comment: Kindly check the demo and try resizing the view window and try by changing the size of the column as well

Answer (score 0):

the entire row columns are about 12 columns so it should be `col-md-6` or add d-flex to the row itself.

```
<div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-6 ">
                <a href="/login " class="grad2"><img class="landing_button" src="{{ asset('storage/buttons/Login-Icon.png') }}" alt="Login"></a>

            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-md-6  ">

                <a href="/register" class="grad2"><img class="landing_button"  src="{{ asset('storage/buttons/Sign-Up.png') }}" alt="Sign Up"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: how come I tried adding offset-sm or xs for mobile layout on chrome dev tools, it does not reflect changes for mobile?